# iOS Xcode issue when swapping from Tab View Controller to swipe gestures

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I an app I was designing with a Tab View controller, which works fine.

I decided to change from a tab view controller to swipe gestures. However once done, whilst the swipe actions work fine, swapping between views with no issue, when I press a button on one of the screens (which works fine when working in tab view controllers) I get the following error:-

2013-12-23 20:07:57.702 TrialApp[3615:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[CMStepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:to:toQueue:withHandler:], /SourceCache/CoreLocationFramework/CoreLocation-1613.5.2/Framework/CoreMotion/CMStepCounter.mm:211
2013-12-23 20:07:57.704 StepWise[3615:60b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: start'
** First throw call stack:
(0x1839c709c 0x18f945d78 0x1839c6f5c 0x1844f7194 0x1840b35a0 0x1000f039c 0x184541928 0x18398768c 0x1839872fc 0x183985024 0x1838c5b38 0x1892eb830 0x1869040e8 0x1000ef6ec 0x18ff2faa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Why would would this work fine when in a tab view controller, but fail when swipe actions are employed?

Comment: No way to tell without seeing your code for the swipe gesture recognizer, and what your controller hierarchy is.

Comment: The gesture recogniser was created in storyboard as opposed to writing the code. As for hierarchy, please can you explain? The screens swipe with no issue. It is just when a button is used and code is run after that the issue occurs, yet it doesn't occur when in tabs. Is there a way of seeing the line of code that is erroring?

Comment: What is the swipe recognizer's action method? You must either have code or you've connected it to a segue.You should add an exception breakpoint to you project, that should show you the line with the error. Are you still using a tab bar controller, or are you using  something else?

Comment: I connected it to segue. I added break points but couldn't see the error. Will try again though. I do still have the tab bar controller whilst I was testing, should I not do this?

Comment: I still don't know what you're really doing. What segues are you attaching the gesture recognizer to? The only segues you would normally have are the root view controller type between the tab bar controller and its content controllers -- I don't think you want to connect to those. Did you add an exception breakpoint (that's a project wide thing, not one you put on various lines)?

Comment: Thanks - I did the project wide exception breakpoint and found that a variable was losing its data. Sorted now. Thanks.

Comment: Again not `xcode` please learn what `xcode` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to rdelmar. Found that a variable was losing its data. Sorted as I now store this in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You probably shouldn't store it in NSUserDefaults unless you need that value to persist between launches of the app, that's not what user defaults are meant for (and probably indicates that you're doing something wrong if that's the only way you can make it work).

Comment: Actually it makes perfect sense to store it there. I started one idea and swapped mid flow and now it makes sense to retain. Thanks though.